# JavaFX strange rendering on Windows 7

Tags: java, windows-7, javafx

I have just started working with JavaFX and have come to an obstacle. When I open SceneBuilder it renders very strangely. When the window is restored it seems zoomed in, and when  maximized it looks better, but still not quite OK and inoperable.
The same goes for HelloWorld example that I created, and examples I found on internet, so I think it is something systemic. I have tried with Java 7u71 and with Java 8u25. No change. Please help if you know how to fix this.

Answer (score 3):

After reading system requirements (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/supportedconfigurations-1506746.html) I came across this line:

> To avoid rendering issues on Windows platforms, upgrade the ATI driver to Catalyst 11.09 or later.

If you have a old laptop like I do (with ATI FireGL V5200 and ATI driver 8.561.0.0), try to disable HWA. I did this by setting JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS in Windows Environment variables. See answer: [How to disable or bypass Hardware Graphics Acceleration(Prism) in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754803/how-to-disable-or-bypass-hardware-graphics-accelerationprism-in-javafx)

> For Java 7: JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dprism.order=j2d
>
> For Java 8: JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dprism.order=sw