# JavaFx not rendering properly

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, render

My code consists of two classes one the MainGUI.java and the Screen.java
I intend to make different classes for Different Screens and render them when needed

This is the current code i have for **MainGUI.java**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class MainGUI extends Application{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage pStage) throws Exception {

        Screen firstScreen = new Screen();
        Scene mainScene = new Scene(firstScreen );
        pStage.setScene(mainScene);
        pStage.setTitle("TestProg");
        pStage.show();
    }
}
```

This is the code for Screen.java

```
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;



public class Screen extends VBox{
    private final Label L1 = new Label("Label 1");
    private final Label L2 = new Label("Label 2");
    private final TextField F1 = new TextField();
    private final TextField F2 = new TextField();
    private final Button B1 = new Button("This is a button");

    Screen(){
        super();
        showStuff();
    }
    private void showStuff(){
        this.setSpacing(5);
        this.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        this.setPadding(new Insets(10,0,0,10));
        HBox Box1 = new HBox(L1,F1);
        HBox Box2 = new HBox(L2,F2);
        this.getChildren().addAll(Box1,Box2,B1);
    }
}
```

This are the screenshots of the GUI i get after running the code:

[image: **Screenshot1**]
[image: **Screenshot2**]

I have no idea what information would be of help but but I'm using **jre1.8.0_25**

As you can see from the images the Forms do no show the text properly and also there is a gray rectangle below.

Comment: Works fine on my PC, same jre + Win7.

Comment: jre1.8.0_20 - works for me. What is the problem? Size of the window or these strange artifacts?

Comment: Artifacts, and after i resize i can't input anymore text in the forms.

Comment: @jewelsea your link did the trick, i only had to add  " -Dprism.order=sw ", if you can please include your answer so that i can rate it. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user reports that bypassing the hardware rendering pipeline via a command-line option fixed the issue on their system:

```
-Dprism.order=sw
```

Note that (as of Java 8) the above command-line switch is an undocumented and unsupported feature of the Oracle JavaFX runtime.

See:

- [How to disable or bypass Hardware Graphics Acceleration(Prism) in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754803/how-to-disable-or-bypass-hardware-graphics-accelerationprism-in-javafx)

---

I've seen similar images posted for JavaFX apps on StackOverflow before (though I can't locate the duplicate questions). I could never replicate the images and don't know exactly what causes them.   Likely, the application is running on an out of date video card or video card driver that is not supported by JavaFX.

Comment: expecting this to work on javafx12 and jdk 11, the truth hurt.