# Java FX TextField blur

Tags: javafx, textfield, blur

Can anyone tell me why sometimes JavaFX displays the content of a `TextField` with a blur effect on it? It seems to be random and occurs in any of my `TextField`s. Please see the image attached.

[image]

Comment: Which do you say is blurred? I don't notice any blur effect. Also please include your code.

Comment: Please clarify which `TextField` in your image you're referring to.

Comment: Maybe blur is not the right word but have a look at the first text field "Channels" The symbol "2" is thicker as compared with the "Data Lines" text field symbol "2". I will add some code.

Comment: When you edit your question to include a [mcve] that reproduces the effect, please clarify that you are focused on the `2` glyph. It looks like it's rendered twice, with one copy shifted horizontally relative to the other.

Answer (score 2):

Focusing on the intermittent rendering artifact mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53989299/java-fx-textfield-blur/53989899#comment94845657_53989299), the `2` glyph looks like it's been rendered twice, with one copy shifted horizontally relative to the other. Such apparently random anomalies are notoriously difficult to identify. Myriad causes may include [incorrect synchronization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm), [improper layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/index.html), defects in the host platform's [rendering pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28035408/230513), etc. For reference, the example below may allow you to test on disparate platforms.

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53989899/230513
 */
public class TextFieldTest extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("TextFieldTest");
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setCenter(createContent());
        root.setBottom(createVersion());
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Node createContent() {
        HBox row1 = new HBox(4);
        Label channelsLabel = new Label("Channels:");
        TextField channelsText = new TextField("2");
        channelsText.setPrefWidth(32);
        Label separatorLabel = new Label("Separator:");
        TextField separatorText = new TextField("!");
        separatorText.setPrefWidth(32);
        row1.setPadding(new Insets(8));
        row1.getChildren().addAll(
            channelsLabel, channelsText, separatorLabel, separatorText);
        HBox row2 = new HBox(4, new Label("Label:"), new TextField());
        row2.setPadding(new Insets(8));
        return new VBox(row1, row2);
    }

    private Label createVersion() {
        Label label = new Label(
            System.getProperty("os.name") + " v"
            + System.getProperty("os.version") + "; Java v"
            + System.getProperty("java.version"));
        label.setPadding(new Insets(8));
        return label;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

As shown in the [Modena](http://fxexperience.com/2013/01/modena-new-theme-for-javafx-8/) example, an intentional blur effect indicates that the text field is [*focused*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#focusedProperty):

[image: text fields]

The detail that gives rise to the blurred effect in your [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miNsz.jpg) is a compound border, seen below at 2x:

[image: text field 2x]

Comparable effects are seen here for buttons (top row) and default buttons (bottom row):

[image: buttons]

Comment: Hi! thank you for the explanation on focus. I am aware of it but my problem is a random rendering bug which applies to the content of the text field. In my picture this is shown as a bold/blur effect on the symbol 2 which appears in the top left text field.

Comment: Hi trashgod! Thanks for the update. I am currently testing a correction to this behaviour. Previously, these texfields were bound biderectionally to String properties stored elsewhere. Although when running the application, the first thing required was a reset of the String properties, this didn't synchronize with clearing the TextFields. I now avoid binding and instead call a thread to clear the TextFields first and then display the values of the corresponding String properties. It seems to work and if it is confirmed for a few days I will come back with a working example.