# NullPointerException when using comboBox in Mac

Tags: javafx

An exception raised when I used the comboBox. Never see this before. but today it just raised. And below is the full stack. Anyone know how can I find where is this bug comes from? It seems like a bug in JavaFX. I am using MAC OS.

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ComboBoxListViewSkin.queryAccessibleAttribute(ComboBoxListViewSkin.java:593)
at javafx.scene.control.Control.queryAccessibleAttribute(Control.java:917)
at javafx.scene.control.ComboBoxBase.queryAccessibleAttribute(ComboBoxBase.java:459)
at javafx.scene.control.ComboBox.queryAccessibleAttribute(ComboBox.java:616)
at javafx.scene.Node$19.getAttribute(Node.java:9648)
at com.sun.glass.ui.Accessible$GetAttribute.run(Accessible.java:142)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.Accessible.lambda$getAttribute$4(Accessible.java:169)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.glass.ui.Accessible.getAttribute(Accessible.java:166)
at com.sun.glass.ui.mac.MacAccessible.accessibilityAttributeValue(MacAccessible.java:1261)
```

Comment: Provide a code in order for the viewers to know what went wrong.

Comment: Have a look on this bug. A workaround has been found by overriding the skin and especially the method `queryAccessibleAttribute`. Note for further question, that the JavaFX version you use, (like the OS on which the bug happens) could be important.

Comment: This [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53989899/230513) illustrates adding a version display to your [mcve].

Comment: I realized I forget the [URL of the bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8184270) I was talking about in the previous comment :).