# JavaFX app closes when taken off focus

Tags: javafx

I'm new to an approximately 50K-line Java project using JavaFX, and I'm getting a bug nobody else in the group seems to be able to duplicate.  Unfortunately I can't share any code, so this is just a hope that this is a familiar issue to anyone else, or that there are suggestions about how to think about and solve this problem.

The application itself is a launcher with five different modes.  The minimum working system requires running two different instances of the application and starting mode #1 in the first and mode #2 in the second.  The two communicate with each other over IP.

Mode #1 works fine, stays open indefinitely; at any rate, I haven't been able to make it close unexpectedly. Mode #2 is the problem.  After opening Mode #2, if I click on any other window, taking focus off of it, the window disappears within a second or two.  I get no error message or any other symptom.  The eclipse console just reads  at the top.  If I don't click elsewhere, it runs several minutes at least without comment.

I have no idea how to go about solving this problem.  I can't seem to use a debugger because it doesn't seem to hold onto memory after crashing.  There's nothing about crashing when the focus is taken off that matches up with any of my knowledge.

It's a simple window, two buttons, a menu, and an output text box.

With these clues, do you have any suggestions about how to proceed?

Comment: Some info that may be relevant: 1. What OS are you using? 2. What version of Java are you using? 3. Does the same happen when not running from withing Eclipse?    

Things to check in the code - does the stage or any control have a listener set on the focus property? Do you at any point change the default uncaught exception handler to one that may not show an exception?   

Did you try updating your GPU drivers? Or using the [software pipeline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754803/how-to-disable-or-bypass-hardware-graphics-accelerationprism-in-javafx)?

Comment: You could try to reduce your program to a [minimal, viable example](http://www.sscce.org/), while still retaining the bug behaviour. That way you can share the code and it becomes a lot more likely that someone here will be able to help. or even for you to help yourself.