# JavaFx Window white after graphics driver crash or update

Tags: java, javafx

I recently noticed that open JavaFx Applications are blank (white scene) after a graphic driver crash or update and i am wondering why that is since Swing applications, Windows, Eclipse or Chrome show now problems.

I now that JavaFx is rendered via GPU but so are Websites in Chrome.

Can someone explain to me why a JavaFx Application ist not usable anymore after such driver crash or normal driver update.

P.S.
At work we have some PCs that suffer multiple driver crashes daily this seems to be an issue with intel GPU and Windows 10 drivers for some of our workstations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the most likely explanation is that Java graphics libraries do not not cope with the GPU drivers crashing.  Its not that surprising (to me) that this happens.  After all, it is a bug in the OS platform.

There's not really much you can do about it except (maybe) running the JVM with graphics acceleration turned off.  This Q&A explains how:

- [How to disable or bypass Hardware Graphics Acceleration(Prism) in JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754803/how-to-disable-or-bypass-hardware-graphics-accelerationprism-in-javafx)

A better long term approach would be get a fix for the flakey drivers.   Have you talked to the PC vendor?  Have you tried looking for a driver update from Intel for your graphics chip / card?

Another way to approach this (if you had an Oracle Java support contract) would be to ask Oracle support for help / advice.

---

Why does it happen on Java and not Google Chrome?  Maybe because Google Chrome's internal architecture uses a different process for each browser window / tab.  So when it detects a GPU crash, it may be able to nuke the process for the tab and start a new one ... pretty much transparently to the user.

This is just a theory ...