# JavaFX 0x300b: Could not get EGL surface

Tags: java, javafx, raspberry-pi, buildroot

I'm trying to run a javafx sample on a raspaberry pi 3 in a embedded environment (buildroot), i want to run it without X.  when i run the command:

```
/root/jre-13.0.1/bin/java  -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -Dprism.verbose=true -Djavafx.verbose=true -Dglass.platform=Monocle -Dprism.order=es2 -Djava.library.path=/root/jre-13.0.1/lib/ -Dembedded=monocle   -jar /home/root/NetBeansProjects//JavaFXFXML/dist/JavaFXFXML.jar
```

i get the following error:

```
cmd : cd '/home/root/NetBeansProjects//JavaFXFXML'; '/root/jre-13.0.1//bin/java'  -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -Dprism.verbose=true -Djavafx.verbose=true -Dglass.platform=Monocle -Dprism.order=es2 -Djava.library.path=/root/jre-13.0.1/lib/ -Dembedded=monocle   -jar /home/root/NetBeansProjects//JavaFXFXML/dist/JavaFXFXML.jar 
JavaFX launchApplication method: launchMode=LM_JAR
Prism pipeline init order: 
es2 
Using Double Precision Marlin Rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Using system sized mask for primitives
Not 
f
orcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Loading ES2 native library ... prism_es2_monocle
Loaded /root/jre-13.0.1/lib/libprism_es2_monocle.so from java.library.path
    succeeded.
GLFactory using com.sun.prism.es2.MonocleGLFactory
Loaded /root/jre-13.0.1/lib/libglass_monocle.so from java.library.path
com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.GLException: 0x300b: Could not get EGL surface
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.AcceleratedScreen.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.NativePlatform.getAcceleratedScreen(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.es2.MonocleGLFactory.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.prism.GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
GraphicsPipeline.createPipeline: error initializing pipeline com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2
```

I ran the hello_triangle and hello_dispmanx examples to test gpu accelaration and there where no problems.
Don't know why i'm getting the `Could not get EGL surface` error, is there any way to debug this error

Java settings:

```
# java --version
openjdk 13.0.1-BellSoft 2019-10-15
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 13.0.1-BellSoft+9)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 13.0.1-BellSoft+9, mixed mode)
```

Comment: You could try [switching off the hardware rendering pipeline and using the software rendering pipeline instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18754803/how-to-disable-or-bypass-hardware-graphics-accelerationprism-in-javafx) and see if that works.

Comment: using SW Pipeline works, I Just want to try using hardware accelaration

Comment: Try contacting BellSoft, your JDK vendor, and asking them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally I figured out...
Since I'm using **buildroot** all raspberry pi userland (GPU) libraries are in the `/usr/lib` folder. However, going deep in the monocle source code, more precisely in the [DispmanPlatformFactory.java](https://github.com/TestFX/Monocle/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sun/glass/ui/monocle/DispmanPlatformFactory.java#L34), we can see the the way they match the platform is to search for the libbcm_host.so in `/opt/vc/lib` which does not exist in the buildroot configuration. A quick workaround for those who use buildroot is to create a symbolic link to `libbcm_host.so` in `/opt/vc/lib`